# Loading the same named library from different folder

Tags: c#, dll, com

I have C# .Net 4.0 COM interoperable libraries which uses the same common helper libraries...

For ex: 
.Net COM interop Library 1 (say library name : netCom1.dll)
.Net COM interop library 2 (say library name : netCom2.dll)
 Both referring to same (Common libraries) lib1.dll, lib2.dll and lib3.dll.

And Their output directory are
.Net COM interop Library 1 /bin => netCom1.dll, lib1.dll, lib2.dll and lib3.dll.
.Net COM interop Library 2 /bin => netCom2.dll, lib1.dll, lib2.dll and lib3.dll

Now, these COM interop libraries run in the Single frame process. (Frame.exe).
But what I observed is, eventhough common libraries lib1.dll, lib2.dll and lib3.dll are in different folders for netCom1.dll and netCom2.dll, when it is run the frame,exe, these common libraries are loaded only once i.e. static variables are the same for netCom1.dll and netCom2.dll.

Is there any way that I can make netCom1.dll to refer its folder's lib1.dll, lib2.dll and lib3.dll and netCom2.dll to refer its folder's lib1.dll, lib2.dll and lib3.dll when both com operable libraries are loaded in the single frame process.

Comment: What is the nature of these `libX.dll` libraries - are they .NET assemblies, COM DLLs or just plain windows DLLs?

Comment: Common libraries (libX.dll) are simple .Net 4.0 dlls.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to create multiple AppDomains inside your process and run each code in its own AppDomain.

Comment: Is there any way other than creating AppDomain ? Also I dont have any control over the process as it is frame and we both talk to each other via COM interfaces only..